# In CSS/JavaScript, how is this icon/font plugin implemented?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fonts

Demo at Jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/hc046u9u/

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.0/css/materialize.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<i class="material-icons">add</i>
<i class="material-icons">replay</i>
```

What confused me the most is the icons are not implemented by class attribute (like `<i class="icon-add"></i>` or `<i class="icon-reply"></i>`), but by the **inner text** of the `<i>` node.

When I view the `<i>` node in the developer tool of chrome, they look almost the same and seem indistinguishable for CSS selector.

[image]

If the icon is set by the inner text, how could CSS asign different icons for these `<i>` nodes?

Another thing that I could not understand is how these icons are implemented (icon font, [PNG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics) or [SVG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics)). It seems that they are implemented by `icon font`, **but I can't find any CSS declaration like**:

```
.fa-flag:before {
  content: "\f024";
}
```

If the icons is not implemented by the `:before` selector and `content` attribute, how are they implemented?

Comment: It's an imported font file ?

Comment: The woff files comes from [here](https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons)

Comment: @hanfeisun The icons are implemented by class. It so happened that the icons were from the font family 'Material Icons'.

Comment: @adeneo I see there is a woff file, but how can the content of `<i>` node be replaced by the encoding of the character in the Woff file?

Comment: @AlbertoI.N.J.  Thanks, but I didn't see the inner text of the `<i>` node be replaced by the encoding of special characters, such as `"\f024"`. Moreover, I can't find the setting of special character by CSS..

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's a "trick" where the icons are implemented as composed glyphs in the font. It means that letter combinations "add" and "replay" are displayed as one character in the font, similar to how "fi" and "fl" are often represented as one character in many fonts. (See [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographic_ligature) for more information.) The icons therefore don't come from CSS declarations.

You can see how it works if you apply the font to an input field: if you start typing randomly, you don't see anything because individual characters don't have a glyph assigned to them, but if you type "add" you'll see a + symbol appear.

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

<textarea class="material-icons">add remove replay</textarea>
```

Comment: The term is [ligature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographic_ligature). *(I was too slow by 23 seconds. :-) )* (Edit: Oh, sorry, I didn't realize you'd linked exactly that article!)

Comment: @ hanfeisun: It sounds like you're used to icon fonts like Font Awesome that do it with `::before`, but there's no reason it can't be done with ligatures other than that the element content is *content*, and so it's important that the text be appropriate to where it's used. With Font Awesome and similar, you can use `fa-close` for any purpose you want (not just "closing" something) without it become part of the *content* of the page. But if you control the font generator, you can create a ligature font tuned to your app, and you get your icon *and* indexable/screen-readable text all together.

Comment: I'd also recommend anybody to read [issue #371 @ alistapart](http://alistapart.com/article/the-era-of-symbol-fonts) about symbol fonts which covers ligatures as well.

Comment: While this is a neat trick, it breaks when translating a page or if you want to use that font for non-english sites. You will need a version of that font for every language, which may become impractical.

Comment: @SimonLehmann, excellent point. This trick leads to internationalization headaches.