# In CSS/SVG, ligature font doesn't work in `<text>` nodes?

Tags: javascript, css, html, svg, fonts

Here is a Demo at JsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/d0t3yggb/

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="material-icons">add add add add</div>
<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1000 300" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <defs>
        <path id="MyPath" d="M 100 200 
             C 200 100 300   0 400 100
             C 500 200 600 300 700 200
             C 800 100 900 100 900 100" />
    </defs>
    <use xlink:href="#MyPath" fill="none" stroke="red" />
    <text class="material-icons">
        <textPath xlink:href="#MyPath">add add add add</textPath>
    </text>
    <!-- Show outline of the viewport using 'rect' element -->
    <rect x="1" y="1" width="998" height="298" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" />
</svg>
```

Here I used the `'Material Icons'` font, which can convert letter combinations "add" into one character (ligature, explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31089700/in-css-javascript-how-is-this-icon-font-plugin-implemented#31089700)), which looks like below:

[image]

I used `class="material-icons"` to set the `font-family`. This works well for the `<div>` node, as can be seen in the Demo above.

But it doesn't work for the `<text>` node within `<svg>`, the text/characters don't appear at all..

If I remove the `class="material-icons"` attribute from `<text>` node, the text appears:

[image]

but it is not the "'Material Icons'" font...

Does anyone have ideas about this?

Comment: IIRC SVG text rendering doesn't support ligatures - at least in some browsers.  You will need to use the actual character code for the glyph.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau Thanks! But how can I get the actual character code? For example, the actual character code for `add` ligature..

Comment: Looks like they are all listed here in the GIT repo: https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/blob/master/iconfont/codepoints

Comment: I put all the info and a demo into an answer.

Comment: have you tried self-hosting the font with an appropriate @font-face in your SVG's <defs>? I can't help but feel the google automatic stylesheet may be interacting poorly with the SVG.... I could be wrong though.

Comment: It works on Firefox.

Comment: It would seem the W3 SVG standard is not as closely followed in most browsers as we would like... Chrome's Blink engine seems to disregard almost all of the rules related to ligatures and web-fonts when rendering SVG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC SVG text rendering doesn't support ligatures - at least in some browsers. You will need to use the actual character code for the glyph.

It looks like they are all listed here in the [GIT repo](https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/blob/master/iconfont/codepoints).  The code for "add" is (hex) e145. So you can include that character in your text using `&#xe145;`.

[Demo fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/d0t3yggb/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Could you try importing the font using css after downloading

```
@font-face {
font-family: material icons;
src: url(material-icons.ttf);
}
```

and then changing your text tag contents to

```
<text font-family="material-icons" font-size="20">
<textPath xlink:href="#MyPath">
 add add add add
</textPath>
 </text>
```